# facebook for android

Tags: android, facebook

I have used facebook application for one of my android application. But i need to implement as such as a native facebook application.

I have used Webview to display feeds and messages in FB application. I need to create a native FB application. I am using JSON as web service. I need to make my FB application as it looks as a native FB application for android application. There is a vast difference of what i have done and the native application.

Any sample working code will be a great help for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for hackbook for android on devloper.facebook.com its provide a demo for your start